# Domino Designer - Hide an empty column of a view and create a border for column

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

How can I hide the empty column of a view (the last part)? I am using embedded view so I do not want that part to appear. Also, how can I create a column border in a view since only row border are available.

[image]

Comment: Hi Louis, re hiding the last column, can't you simply resize the embedded view in its properties box to give the width up to the end of 'Recommendation?

Comment: Also in the View properties tick 'Extend Last Column To Window Width on the 3rd Tab - Style.

Comment: I have multiple columns that it won't fit on the window. I am using scrollbar to view the full details so I want to remove that unnecessary empty column.

Comment: And to make a border, you could add an empty column, with formula "", size 1, font sizes 1, don't show header, not resizeable. Or with a vertical bar in it. Oops, sorry, I tried that, it looks awful. Forget it.

Comment: Ticking Extend Last Column to Window Width should remove the empty column, works for me.